# Парсинг динамических страниц

Tags: парсер

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();    
webpage
  .open('http://example.com') 
  .then(function(){     
    var someContent = webpage.evaluate(function () { 
        [может CALLBACK?] return document.querySelector("#aDiv").textContent;
    });
  });
```

SlimerJS. Подключается к странице. Вызов проходит один раз. Но страница продолжает динамически меняться. Как реализовать постоянный перехват этого события?

Answer (score 1):

**Есть 2 варианта:**

> 1 поставить на settimeout
>
> 2 сравнить полученный ответ от предедущего если они разные то выводить
>   полученный ответ если они одинаковые выводить предедущий ответ.

Comment: #2 то что надо! Но у меня эта конструкция срабатывает 1 раз только. Как можно пристроить туда функцию обратного вызова, которая будет срабатывать каждый раз при изменении страницы?